# How can I store HashMap in Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have to store an object in Redis use Spring Redis. The Object is

```
@RedisHash(value = "shoppingcart")
public class ShoppingCart {
  @Id
  private String cartGuid;
  private Map<String, List<CartItemDto>> promotionProductMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<CartItemDto>>();
  private LinkedList<CartItemDto> cartItems = new LinkedList<>();
....
}
```

CartItemDto look like this

```
public class CartItemDto implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7047005024550867744L;
  private String cartItemId;
  private Long productId;
...
}
```

I have an repository to save into Redis

```
@Repository
public interface ShoppingCartRepository extends CrudRepository<ShoppingCart, String> {
}
```

But when I tried to store shoppingCart by

```
shoppingCartRepository.save(shoppingCart);
```

It throw Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type java.util.LinkedList is not of type of the persistent entity (com.test.CartItemDto)!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:397) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver.doResolveIndexesFor(PathIndexResolver.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver.access$000(PathIndexResolver.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver$1.doWithPersistentProperty(PathIndexResolver.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver$1.doWithPersistentProperty(PathIndexResolver.java:95) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver.doResolveIndexesFor(PathIndexResolver.java:95) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.PathIndexResolver.resolveIndexesFor(PathIndexResolver.java:79) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.write(MappingRedisConverter.java:357) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.write(MappingRedisConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.put(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:183) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate$1.doInKeyValue(KeyValueTemplate.java:168) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate$1.doInKeyValue(KeyValueTemplate.java:158) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:377) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    ... 156 more
```

If I remove promotionProductMap, it can save shoppingCart
I don't know why it can't save Hashmap, with List it can
Anyone know how can I save a Hashmap to Redis?

Comment: There is no way to save a list of complex objects to redis, please check its [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types). You have to restructure your object to be able to cache it. It is very restrictive for fast speed, so such complex objects cannot be stored.